# How to use logger with dependecy injection for whole app?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I want to use Logger in my PHP application globally.
I know how to use it with a Singleton pattern but I saw that people recommend using dependency injection.
I know how dependency injection works in general but the problem is how I can use it "globally" like Singleton in the whole app.
I tried to create an instance in index.php and send it to the first calling of one service.
Should I send that particular instance deeper or should I whenever I want to use logger in class send new instance of logger?

Comment: As long as the object doesn't retain states that may affect the next calls behavior, it is not important how you are instantiating,

Comment: @revo I create, let's say, basic OOP app but I want to use the logger. I can create a bs app but the purpose is to learn best practices so thats why I ask.

Comment: You could create a registry class which is globally available. And call `Registry::getLogger();` where needed. This could be responsible managing a single instance. [Example](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/Registry/README.html)